# Problems with using .InnerHtml in ASP.NET c #

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, innerhtml

I have a div in the aspx page which i gave the attribute runat = "server" and id = "content".
When starting the page I need to create some cards with data taken from a database. But it gives me error when I try from code behind in c # using content.InnerHtml to add html code.

aspx page

```
<div class="page-wrapper">
            <div class="page-content" runat="server" id="contenuto">

            </div>
</div>
```

code behind

```
contenuto.InnerHtml += "<div class='row'>";
```

it gives me this error: "Could not get the internal content of content because it is not in literal format."

[image of the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6Srs.png)

Comment: Tested your snippet. It works fine...

Comment: If there are any other controls with runat=server set inside contenuto, you cannot take this approach.

Answer (score -1):

"contenuto" not containing any server control inside it, you required to change your code like below -

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
String innertext =sb.Append("Text what you required or tag");
contenuto.InnerHtml = innertext ;
```

Comment: This does not even compile....

Comment: add this and then try to run -  using System.Text;

Comment: I doesnt work, it gaves me error, i post an answer to explain better this error, pls help me.

Comment: Using sb.toString() it works.

Thanks